# merging queries and data from 2 tables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables that I need to query different data from. The common link is the datetime column. I have tried to merge the queries but keep getting various errors...

The final query should give me: `date, Peak Power each Day, KWHOpenHrs, KWHClosedTotal`

Any help is appreciated.

The 2 tables are below

`Peak KVA` table

```
Date | Power_Apparent_Total
```

Query:

```
SELECT
   CAST(t.HD as DATE), MAX(t.Power_Apparent_Total) as 'Peak Power Each Day'
FROM [Peak kVA] t
GROUP BY CAST(t.HD AS DATE)
```

`Daily Consumption`

```
Date | KWH Open | KWH ClosedandOccupied | KWH ClosedandnotOccupied
```

Query:

```
select date, 
max(value) kWhOpenHrs,
sum(case when col in ('zkWhClsedAndOccupied', 'zkWhClsedAndNotOccupied') then value   end) kWhClsedTotal
from 
(
  select date, 'zkWhOpenHrs' as col, kWhOpenHours as value
  from dbo.tblDailyPowerConsumption
  union all
  select date, 'zkWhClsedAndNotOccupied' as col, kWhClosedAndNotOccupied as value
  from dbo.tblDailyPowerConsumption
  union all
  select date, 'zkWhClsedAndOccupied' as col, kWhClosedAndOccupied as value
  from dbo.tblDailyPowerConsumption
) src
WHERE MONTH(date) = '12' 
group by date
```

Comment: Can you add a tag denoting the SQL product you are using (including the version, if possible)?

Comment: You should be able to join the two queries in one expression.  If you already tried that, post the complete code you are running and the error messages you get.

Comment: Hi I am using SQL2008, I have tried going back to basics but can't get 'JOIN' to work, as soon as i join the 2 tables on the 2 date columns I get no data...  here's my query... SELECT [Peak kVA].HD
     , [Peak kVA].Power_Apparent_Total
     , tblDailyPowerConsumption.Date
     , tblDailyPowerConsumption.kWhOpenHours
     , tblDailyPowerConsumption.kWhClosedAndOccupied
     , tblDailyPowerConsumption.kWhClosedAndNotOccupied
FROM
  dbo.[Peak kVA]
  INNER JOIN dbo.tblDailyPowerConsumption
    ON [Peak kVA].HD = tblDailyPowerConsumption.Date
WHERE
  month(tblDailyPowerConsumption.Date) = '12'

Comment: I'm assuming you **say** SQL2008 but you **really mean** SQL Server 2008 - right? Added tag. (SQL = Structured Query Language - just a language and a ISO/ANSI Language Spec - **not** an actual product!)

Answer (score 0):

for a start execute this request. Your type of date contains not only date but also time

```
SELECT [Peak kVA].HD AS [date], [Peak kVA].Power_Apparent_Total,
       tblDailyPowerConsumption.kWhOpenHours, 
       tblDailyPowerConsumption.kWhClosedAndOccupied, 
       tblDailyPowerConsumption.kWhClosedAndNotOccupied 
FROM dbo.[Peak kVA] LEFT JOIN dbo.tblDailyPowerConsumption 
                      ON CAST([Peak kVA].HD AS date) = CAST(tblDailyPowerConsumption.Date AS date) 
                        AND MONTH(tblDailyPowerConsumption.Date) = '12'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select date, [Peak Power each Day], KWHOpenHrs, KWHClosedTotal
from
   (SELECT
        CAST(t.HD as DATE), MAX(t.Power_Apparent_Total) as 'Peak Power Each Day'
    FROM [Peak kVA] t
    GROUP BY CAST(t.HD AS DATE)) peak
inner join
   (select date, 
    max(value) kWhOpenHrs,
    sum(case when col in 
       ('zkWhClsedAndOccupied', 'zkWhClsedAndNotOccupied') 
       then value end) kWhClsedTotal
   from 
   (
   select date, 'zkWhOpenHrs' as col, kWhOpenHours as value
   from dbo.tblDailyPowerConsumption
   union all
   select date, 'zkWhClsedAndNotOccupied' as col, kWhClosedAndNotOccupied as value
   from dbo.tblDailyPowerConsumption
   union all
   select date, 'zkWhClsedAndOccupied' as col, kWhClosedAndOccupied as value
   from dbo.tblDailyPowerConsumption
   ) src
   WHERE MONTH(date) = '12' 
   group by date) daily
on peak.date = daily.date
```